# Process hanging on the process builder

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, deadlock

I am working on java process builder to execute the windows external process(i.e., exe files). I have to get the process info and error using input stream, error stream to write it in some text files.

It's working sometimes and unexpectedly hanging sometimes.

When i invoke around three external process to execute one by one. Two process working and it's getting hang on third process only.

I could see the process exit value as 0 some times it's giving some other random value.

I have read the below blog and applied the same logic to execute the process but's not working for my scenarios.

Could anybody please help me to diagnose these problem...

//Starts to initiate the external process
 //This code will pick three arguments from to execute the process sequentially
 //it will pass the process commands through for loop one by one

```
 Process p =new ProcessBuilder(s)
               .directory(new File(je.getExecution().getWorkingDirectory()))
               .redirectErrorStream(true)
               .redirectOutput(file)
               .start();

p.getOutputStream().close();
int processStatus= p.waitFor();
```

// if the process exits with 0 normal termination

Thanks in advance..,

Comment: Likely you're not consuming stdout/stderr, although there are other pitfalls. Highly recommend you read http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: @Adam I'm consuming stdout/stderr. My issue is it's handing sometimes on third process. I will invoke three process sequentially. I don't know why it's getting failed to invoke third process

Comment: How about some code pls

Comment: @SouravGanguly Updated the code in my question. Please take a look

Comment: @SouravGanguly Any idea about that code

Comment: Try `process.getOutputStream().close()` before `process.waitFor();`

Comment: @Guillaume F Okay. Let me try now quickly

Comment: @GuillaumeF. What's the root cause you have identified to add the above code ?

Comment: If your process is waiting for inputs (like a console), and you are waiting for it to terminate, you are both waiting for each-other. Closing the output stream is similar to typing CTRL+C in the process console.

Answer (score 2):

The entire thing you are doing is error prone and it’s not worth trying to find out all of the mistakes, as you are making your life unnecessarily hard.

Note that you are calling `redirectErrorStream(true)`, but still are trying to read from the error stream, which makes no sense. The error stream will always be empty under this condition. That said, if you already know about redirections, it’s not clear, why you don’t use them directly, instead of creating threads, manually copying data into `StringWriter`s, etc.

Apparently, you want to use the working directory `je.getExecution().getWorkingDirectory()`, launch the command `s` and directing both, output and error, of the program to `file`. This can be achieved as easy as

```
new ProcessBuilder(s)
    .directory(je.getExecution().getWorkingDirectory())
    .redirectErrorStream(true).redirectOutput(file)
    .start()
    .waitFor();
```

The only remaining error source is that the launched process could wait for input from your side. Since you apparently don’t want to provide input, you can use

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(s)
    .directory(je.getExecution().getWorkingDirectory())
    .redirectErrorStream(true).redirectOutput(file)
    .start();
proc.getOutputStream().close();
proc.waitFor();
```

to denote that you won’t write any data. This will not stop the process, but when it tries to read something from its standard input, it will immediately get an end-of-file without blocking.

Which can be demonstrated with

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "pause")
    .redirectErrorStream(true).redirectOutput(file)
    .start();
proc.getOutputStream().close();
proc.waitFor();
```

Comment: Will it work without hanging any process. redirectOutput(file) writing the string into one line without breaking in newLine(). Do you have any idea to write the string into newLine ?

Comment: In my development windows 7 64-bit machine it's working as expected when i have used your code. I want to test it in my deployment environment machine windows server. Hope it will work.

Comment: It's failing to finish the process sometimes.

Comment: The redirection is handled on the OS level and writes the data exactly as written, i.e. there is a new line exactly where the sub process produced a newline. You original code reading and writing the output line by line wouldn’t introduce newlines either. It may only happen, that an implicit conversion happens, as `BufferedReader` will interpret all kinds of newline (`\r\n`, `\n`, `\r`) and `PrintWriter` always uses the platform specific newline sequence. Normally, this shouldn’t be necessary. If the subprocess still hangs occasionally, there must be a deeper problem.

Comment: Showing the output line is doesn't matter for me. I'm just writing the log to see any error occurs while invoking the external process. Sometimes the process not terminating with exit values 0. Updated the code in my quesion. Please take a look

Comment: Well, as said, since we can preclude a relationship to the input/output streams now, there must be a deeper problem, probably entirely unrelated to the way you launch the subprocess. So this might be related to the actual program you run in the subprocess or the sever environment.

Comment: As we discussed about the subprocess hanging. It's sometimes getting failed even after i have closed the outputstream after reading it. I have three process to execute sequentially using for loop. It's normal node.exe process with some javascript file invocation. My deployment environment is windows server. Is there any issue on running Windows server env ?